# Adding datatable to dataset creates 2 identical tables in dataset, is there another way to add?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dataset, datarow

Just an FYI, I know there are different ways to handle this, but I need it to work in this particular way for my project.

I create a DataSet(DS) and a DataTable(DT) from a DataSet I created with the DataSetGenerator in VS2010, I then add a row to the DT with some data. I then try to add the DT (which contains data in a row) to the DS. At this point in Visual Studio when I step into the next line of code, the DataSet Visualizer shows I have a DataSet with 2 identically named tables, HOWEVER, one of them has data and the other does not. This is probably an oversight on my behalf but I can't identify it. Still learning C# here so that doesn't help either. Thanks for any help!

**OLD CODE**

```
private string getStorageKey(string strStorageAccount)
    {
        DataSetStorageKeyDetails ds = new DataSetStorageKeyDetails();
        DataSetStorageKeyDetails.StorageKeyDetailsDataTable dt = new DataSetStorageKeyDetails.StorageKeyDetailsDataTable();
        string strStorageKey = "";

        dt.Rows.Add(strStorageAccount);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        DataSet dsOut = ServiceEnclosed.InterfaceService("GetStorageKey", ds);

        DataTable dtr = dsOut.Tables[0];
        DataSetStorageKeyDetails.StorageKeyDetailsRow dr = dt.First();
        strStorageKey = dr.StorageName;            

        return strStorageKey;
    }
```

**NEW CODE**

```
private string getStorageKey(string strStorageAccount)
    {
        DataSetStorageKeyDetails ds = new DataSetStorageKeyDetails();
        string strStorageKey = "";

        ds.StorageKeyDetails.Rows.Add(strStorageAccount);
        DataSet dsOut = ServiceEnclosed.InterfaceService("GetStorageKey", ds);

        DataTable dtr = new DataTable();
        dtr = dsOut.Tables[0];
        strStorageKey = dtr.Rows[0]["StorageKey"].ToString();

        return strStorageKey;
    }
```

Comment: What is the DataSetStorageKeyDetails class? I searched Google for it and haven't found any information about it.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, Sorry, the DataSet and DataTable are ones I created with the DataSetGenerator.

Comment: Your variable names are confusing. The `ds` variable is a `DataSetStorageKeyDetails` object. The `dt` variable is a `StorageKeyDetailsDataTable`, yet you use both `ds` and `dt` as if they were a `DataSet` and `DataTable`. Unless we know what the DataSetStorageKeyDetails and StorageKeyDetailsDataTable classes are, we won't be able to answer your question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt when you add a DataSet to your project via design, it is created as it's own dataset type. All the tables and tablerows it contains become properties, but you treat them just like any other dataset and datatable.. This means, for example, that the dataset he added to his form is named `DataSetStorageKeyDetails`

Comment: Just for curiosity, what's the use of the `dtr` DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a DataSet with the DataSetGenerator, the tables you specify are automatically created when the DataSet is created. You don't have to add a new table, just access the one it already has.

```
private string getStorageKey(string strStorageAccount)
    {
        DataSetStorageKeyDetails ds = new DataSetStorageKeyDetails();
        string strStorageKey = "";

        ds.StorageKeyDetails.Rows.Add(strStorageAccount);

        DataSet dsOut = ServiceEnclosed.InterfaceService("GetStorageKey", ds);

        DataTable dtr = dsOut.Tables[0];
        strStorageKey = ds.StorageKeyDetails.Rows[0].StorageName;            

        return strStorageKey;
    }
```

Untested code, but I think it points you to te right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tweaked a little more but you definitely got me back on the right path. I'll edit my post with my final working code. To answer your other question, dtr is another datatable because the returned values from the WCF need to be read as a datatable in my program instead of as a dataset.